# Add one to a variable when another variable changes

Tags: php

How would I go about adding one to variable when another variable changes value?

Comment: And who would change said variable?

Comment: if($change != $change) $one++, but i've not understend all

Comment: I think he wants to detect when any variable change it's value. Impossible to detect it automatically.

Comment: @AlexBall this code makes no sense whatsoever.  the `if` condition will always be `false`

Comment: There is nothing in php to make that possible. Only if you would encapsulate said variable inside an object, and only use setters/getters to manipulate it, would you be able to achieve your desired result.

Comment: The variable is getting read from an array which would have the same value many times but then change when the data changed.

Comment: @AleksG yes, you are right, mean: control a var and if is different to precedent value (I assume that precedent value is stored in many way) increment another var.  My error to name $change 2 times, I'm sorry.

Comment: It's not entirely impossible. If the observable variable resides in an object, you can use magic methods to intercept its change; and thus increase/set the associated flag. Likewise possible if you override the ArrayAccess interface to simulate your observable variable in an array. (Not sure if worth it or that what's being asked here...)

Answer (score 5):

Encapsulate the variable inside a class instance and require calling a method to increment that variable.  When the method is called, either increment the other variable explicitly or use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) so you can add arbitrary incrementers at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add one to the variable when you change the other variable.
There's no way to make that happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to create a good answere to your question since it does not tell anything about how you're setting this `$another_variable` or what it is. But here is my suggestion:

```
$variable = 1;
$orginal_variable = 'orginal value to another_variable';
$another_variable = ($_GET['new-value']) ? $_GET['new-value'] : $orginal_variable;
$variable = ($another_variable != $orginal_variable) ? ($variable + 1) : $variable ;

echo $variable;
```

In order to detect any changes in PHP, I do believe you need to have the orginal value avalible somewhere in your script to compare with. In this case, you need to have the orginal value from `$another_variable`.

```
$orginal_variable = 'orginal value to another_variable';
```

Once you have that, you could do what I did:

```
$another_variable = ($_GET['new-value']) ? $_GET['new-value'] : $orginal_variable ;
```

Either set `$another_variable` to a new value fetched from somewhere (e.g. from a `_GET` or `_POST`), or leave it identical to the orginal value `$orginal_variable`.

Then you could compare these two values; If `$another_vriable` has changed, meaning it is different from `$orginal_variable`, you could do +1 to `$variable`. Or just leave it as it was if nothing has changed:

```
$variable = ($another_variable != $orginal_variable) ? ($variable + 1) : $variable ;
```